# Can't remote connect to home pc from work

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a Win10 Pro pc at home with remote desktop activated. I am able to connect to it on my local network as well as externally on a public or 3G network (through network sharing on my phone).

However, when I try to connect from work I'm unable to do so. We have external servers which can be connected to from work, but connecting to my home pc does not.

I'm using standard port 3389 on my server. My work pc uses Win10 Enterprise.

Does anyone have any ideas why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how the Company network is configured it's impossible to say for sure. However most companies will filter outbound traffic, chances are that your company simply blocks 3389 outbound.

I would suggest trying an alternative to RDP, such as Teamviewer or Chrome Remote Desktop as these will use port 443 (SSL/TLS). Your company may also filter 443 traffic using a SSL interception for the purpose of Content Filtering and/or Data Loss Prevention, but that's slightly less common than simple port blocking.

Comment: You seem to be correct. I tried to find out what outbound ports were blocked and 3389 seems to be one of them. I guess they can setup exceptions for our corporate external servers which use 3389 as welll. So I guess that forces me to use an alternative.